# PrimeFaces <f:attribute not working correctly with p:galleria attribute

Tags: primefaces

I have issue when trying to make command link from inside p:galleria component 
The problem is despite the fact at run time the link value `value="Show present #{present.name} #{present.presentId}"` contains the correct value of the id as example `value="Show present Foo 1"` , when pressing the command link it sends the wrong id of the second object every time

```
<h:form>
    <p:galleria value="#{presentBean.allPresentList}" var="present" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" showCaption="true">  
        <f:facet name="content">
            <h:commandLink value="Show present #{present.name} #{present.presentId}"                   action="pretty:present" actionListener="#{presentBean.setPresentObj}">
                <f:attribute name="present" value="#{present.presentId}"/>
              </h:commandLink>
        </f:facet>
    </p:galleria> 
</h:form>

@ManagedBean(name="presentBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PresentBean implements Serializable{

    ArrayList<Present> allUserPresentList = new ArrayList<Present>();

    @PostConstruct
    private void usersPresent(){
        PresentDao presentDao = new PresentDaoImpl();
        allPresentList = (ArrayList<Present>) presentDao.findAllPresents();
    }

    public ArrayList<Present> getAllUserPresentList() {
        return allUserPresentList;
    }

    public void setAllUserPresentList(ArrayList<Present> allUserPresentList) {
        this.allUserPresentList = allUserPresentList;
    }

    private String presentId ;

    public String getPresentId() {
        return presentId;
    }

    public void setPresentId(String presentId) {
        this.presentId = presentId;
    }

    public void setPresentObj(ActionEvent ev){
        Object presentOb = ev.getComponent().getAttributes().get("present");
        if(presentOb != null){
            this.presentId = (String) presentOb;
        }else{
            presentId = null ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide your managed bean code

Comment: Thanks  @zargarf for your response ,When i debug method "setPresentObj" the value is fixed and don't change what ever the image that shown in the gallery

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a setPropertyActionListener instead of `<f:attribute name="present" value="#{present.presentId}"/>` as the f:attribute tag is only evaluated when the component is created (only once) not when the component generates html based on the iterated rows.

So you'll need to instead use:

```
 <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{presentBean.presentId}" value="#{present.presentId}" />
```

That will set the value of the presentId in your managed bean, so in your action method you can just access the presentId itself already without having to work it out.

Alternatively if you're using a later version of JSF (using Servlet 3.0 or above), then you could create a method in the managed bean which takes the presentId or even the present object as a parameter

e.g. in your managed bean:

```
 public void myAction(Present p){
       //do whatever you want with the Present object
    }
```

and in your .xhtml:

```
<h:commandLink value="Show present #{present.name} #{present.presentId}"         actionListener="#{presentBean.myAction(present)}">
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , but i feel i reached dead end because even when i used <f:setPropertyActionListener it set the first present only over and over , so i think it is a bug in <p:galleria , any way thank you for your help